# Matlab error on code

Tags: matlab

I am having trouble running this code, the errors that appears due to the "{" brackets but since I haven't had much experience with MATLAB I am unable to find a way to fix them. I know it has to do with the brackets also it appears I am missing ends somewhere.

```
f=@(x) x^3
    a=1;
    b=3;
    tol=0.00005;

for i=1:100
    c=(a+b)/2;

if(c<tol){
    break;
          }

if f(c)>0
    b=c;

else

     a=c;

end
end

a=1;
b=3;
p=c;

for i=1:100
     c=(a+b)/2;

if(c<tol){
    break;
         }

er(i)=f(c)-f(p);

if f(c)>0
  b=c;

else
  a=c;

end
end

fprintf('Calculated Root is %f',c)
     plot(er);
     title('Plot of error')
     xlabel('Number of iterations')
     ylabel('Error')
```

Comment: Your code is barely readable as it is now. Please indent it in order to reflect the structure of your program. Once you've done that, you might find much debugging easier. Also, MATLAB is not a brace language. In particular, `if(c<tol){break;}` is not valid MATLAB syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess what you mean, but what you want is probably

```
f=@(x) x^3

a=1;
b=3;
tol=0.00005;

for i=1:100
   c=(a+b)/2;

   if c<tol
      break;
   end

   if f(c)>0
      b=c;
   else
      a=c;
   end
end

a=1;
b=3;
p=c;

for i=1:100
   c=(a+b)/2;

   if c<tol
      break;
   end

   er(i)=f(c)-f(p);

   if f(c)>0
      b=c;
   else
      a=c;
   end
end

fprintf('Calculated Root is %f',c)
plot(er);
title('Plot of error')
xlabel('Number of iterations')
ylabel('Error')
```

You should probably shortly glance over some short Matlab introductions in order to see how Matlab code is supposed to look.